# How to get all results in a query even though a table has not all ids

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query regarding three tables.

Table 1:

```
id     product_id     product_name
1          1          product1
2          5          product5
3          7          product7
```

Table 2:

```
id     media_id       media_name
1        1            media_1
2        2            media_2
```

Table 3:

```
 id     product_id    media_id
 1       1            1
 2       5            2
```

So I have the query

```
SELECT A.product_id
     , A.product_name
     , B.media_id
     , B.media_name 
  FROM 'Table 1' A
     , 'Table 2' B
     , 'Table 3' C 
 WHERE 1 
   AND A.product_id = C.product_id 
   and B.media_id = C.media_id
```

Possibly there is an error in the structure or query but what I get as an result is only the values from Table1 for product_id 1 and 5 but no info for product_id 7 because there is no media available for product_id 7.

How should I write the query to get results for all products and if a product has no media info just leave the field blank in the results but deliver the info from other tables which have info for this specific product.

Thank you

Comment: Consider using explicit `JOIN` syntax and don't enclose identifiers in single quotes, use back ticks.

Comment: you should use JOIN syntax, and so then use the LEFT/RIGHT JOIN to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `LEFT JOIN`.

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match.

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an [RIGHT JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT
  t1.product_id,    
  t1.product_name,
  t2.media_id,
  t2.media_name
FROM
table3 t3
RIGHT JOIN
table2 t2 ON t3.media_id = t2.media_id
RIGHT JOIN
table1 t1 ON t3.product_id = t1.product_id
```

see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2yKt6d5RWngXVYJKPGZL6m/9

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN

Comment: it exist , so somebody has used it. here it is the best otion to get all from media and product, which numbers are not determine also the join table is no guaranty to have all numbers included-